# Atribuir input a variável

Tags: javascript, funções, input

Estou fazendo um formulário simples de envio. Basicamente: O usuário insere o valor a ser sacado, preenche os dados e ao clicar no botão confirmar,  é exibido o resultado na tela.

O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo criar essa função de envio, para que o código só execute quando o usuário clicar em confirmar. Como proceder?

Segue código:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Valor do saque</label>  
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" value="" type="text" placeholder="R$ 00,00" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como está fazendo o envio? Onde está o botão de enviar?

Comment: Esse envio vai para um servidor?
Esse envio é calculado por javascript?
Esse envio pode ser cancelado?
Por favor, explique melhor seu problema para que possamos te ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Conforme entendi, vc pode fazer assim:

Com **javascript**

```
<button onclick="enviar()">Confirmar</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function enviar(){
        var valor = document.getElementById("textinput").value;
        alert(valor);

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Ou usando **jQuery**:

```
<button id="confirmar">Confirmar</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('click','#confirmar',function(){
        var valor = $('#textinput').val();
        alert(valor);

        return false;
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

O comportamento do exemplo abaixo será o seguinte:
  - Ao clicar no botão confirmar:
    - Apresentará um aviso com o value do campo "valor";
    - Apresentará no escopo a mensagem do value do campo "valor";
    - Não ocorrerá redirecionamento na página, pois dentro do atributo está inserido onsubmit existe além da função "mostrarDados()", o "return false" que para a execução do submit.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="mostrarDados(); return false;">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="valor">Valor do saque</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="valor" name="valor" type="text" placeholder="R$ 00,00" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="confirmar" value="Confirmar">
</form>
<div class="col-md-12" id="resultado"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrarDados(){
    valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;

    // MOSTRARÁ O VALOR IMPRESSO NA TELA
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Valor: "+valor+"<br>";

    // MOSTRARÁ UM AVISO
    alert("Valor: "+valor);
}
```